# Is there a way to exclude an ingress from using my nginx custom default backend?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, ingress-controller

I created a custom default backend for my ingress controller by following these official instructions:
[custom default backend manifests](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/customization/custom-errors/custom-default-backend.yaml)
and it is being referenced in the values.yaml of my nginx ingress controller.

This all works perfectly fine. But this configuration affects my entire cluster.

Is there a way to exclude some ingresses of my deployments from using the custom default backend?

The reason is that I would like to add custom error pages for http errors for my static websites but leave the error page handling of my web-applications internally.